# gnuplot generate plot command with sprintf?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to generate a gnuplot plot command programmatically, like:

```
plotline = sprintf("'datafile1.dat' using %d:3 with points, '%s' using %d:3 with points",i,targfile,i)
plot plotline
```

Where 'plotline' in the second line is expanded to produce and execute a full command like:

```
plot 'datafile1.dat' using 8:3 with points, 'datafile2.dat' using 8:3 with points
```

I want to do this in order to echo 'plotline' in the terminal and so be certain exactly what is being shown while cycling through a set of columns / datafiles / whatever inside a loop in a gnuplot script.

Is there / what is the  syntax to do this, or can you suggest another approach to report the plot command as executed (without splitting into a plot command and a separate set of commands to report the current variable states).

Thanks!

Comment: `sprintf("format",x,...) - result from C-language sprintf`  ... see here http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to construct such a plot command from some strings, you can use `eval` to execute the commands contained in a string:

```
plotline = 'x title "mytitle"'
eval('plot '.plotline)
```

Alternatively you can use `set macros`:

```
set macros
plotline = 'x title "mytitle"'
plot @plotline
```

This replaces `@plotline` with the content of the string variable `plotline` *before* executing the command. Using `plot plotline` interpretes the content of `plotline` as file name. Note, that as of version 4.6 macros don't work properly in loops, but `eval` works fine.

BTW: If you don't specify your own title, then the actual plot statement is written in the plot legend. But that can't be written to the terminal output.

Comment: thanks! was unable to make 'set macros ... @plotline' work for me as plotline from sprintf is 'not a string variable', however eval() does exactly what I was after.

Comment: Thats strange. For me, with 4.6.3, both the following statements work fine: `set macros; plotline = sprintf("%f*x", 4); plot @plotline` and also `set macros; plotline = sprintf("'%s' using 0:1", 'test.txt'); plot @plotline` (of course provided, that you have such a file `test.txt`.

Comment: I would add that with the current 4.6 version macros within a for loop don't work as intended, so the eval version is to be preferred.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the remark, I put the `eval` part first and added a note related to macros and looping.