# Rescale data in gnuplot using settings.gp

Tags: gnuplot, settings, scale

I have a set of plots in Gnuplot. Now I realized that I need to rescale the data which I use, like: `($2-log(0.35))` instead of `$2, $5*0.35` instead of `$5,` etc.

Is it possible to write somehow this changes to some file `settings.gp` and then use it in all my previous `*.gp` files by means of **'load settings.gp'**?

Comment: you can use macros (`help macros`) or have a lok at `eval`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233470/gnuplot-generate-plot-command-with-sprintf

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. Of course you can set a factor e.g. `a=0.35` in an external script file, but you'll have to update your scripts anyway to use it.