# how to create and plot n number of function using a loop in gnuplot

Tags: loops, gnuplot

I have written a code where i am trying to simulate n numbers of bubbles but my problem is that i have to hard code my function as you can see that i am using `fx, fy, fz` then `fx1, fy1, fz1` and `fx2, fy2, fz2`.

Instead of that i want to create my functions using a loop and also want to plot them using a loop.Is there any way to do that.

**Here is the code :**

```
w=1.0
set isosample 50
set parametric
set urange [0:2*pi]
set vrange [-pi/2:pi/2]
do for [w=1:50]  {
  fx(v,u,w)  = w*cos(v)*cos(u)
  fy(v,u,w)  = w*cos(v)*sin(u)
  fz(v,w)    = w*sin(v) 
  fx1(v,u,w) = 20+w*cos(v)*cos(u)
  fy1(v,u,w) = 30+w*cos(v)*sin(u)
  fz1(v,w)   = 30+w*sin(v) 
  fx2(v,u,w) = 40+w*cos(v)*cos(u)
  fy2(v,u,w) = 60+w*cos(v)*sin(u)
  fz2(v,w)   = 60+w*sin(v) 
  splot fx(v,u,w), fy(v,u,w), fz(v,w), fx1(v,u,w), fy1(v,u,w), fz1(v,w), fx2(v,u,w), fy2(v,u,w), fz2(v,w)  with pm3d
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you are trying to achieve?  It seems like you want to generate the functions on the fly, in that case `eval` might be helpful. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21233470/1331399) shows an example of this

Comment: I am trying to give loop while plotting my functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `splot for` syntax of gnuplot:

```
set isosample 50
set parametric
set urange [0:2*pi]
set vrange [-pi/2:pi/2]

fx(v,u)  = 2.0*d + w*cos(v)*cos(u)
fy(v,u)  = 3.0*d + w*cos(v)*sin(u)
fz(v)    = 3.0*d + w*sin(v)   

do for [w=1:50]  {
  splot for [d = 0:20:10] fx(v,u), fy(v,u), fz(v) with pm3d
}
```

I think you want to read these gnuplot help pages: `help for` and `help for loops`. Depending on your needs, you might also want to read `help word` and for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30749160/7010554) or `help array` if you are on gnuplot 5.2.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.it has solved my problem.

Comment: @RajneeshSharma: Please accept the answer that best solves your issue (click the checkmark beside the answer)